# Как Вы защищаете свой ключ?

Tags: google-maps-api

В рекомендациях от Google есть несколько строк информирующих нас о том, что ключ (API_KEY) для карты следует защищать, в частности не вставлять их в открытом виде в код, так как они могут быть скомпрометированны. Что это значит? Как Вы сможете использовать мой ключ? Что с ним можно сделать?

Comment: А есть ли у гугл-мапс платная подписка или ограничения по использованию? Пользуюсь одним сервисом отправки смс [для уведомлений](https://github.com/gil9red/SimplePyScripts/tree/master/Check%20with%20notification) и если кто-то узнает мой API_KEY, то сможет за мой счет смски рассылать

Comment: нет, платной подписки нет, это только для практики, как хобби. Спасибо за внимание.